# Volume of shape that appears between part of circle and a function

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Let $R$ be the surface in the first quadrant limited by the curves $x^2 + y^2 = 5, y = 2x$ and $x=0$. I'm asked to find the volume of the object that appears when $R$ is rotated about the y-axis.

Is there a smart way to represent the curve I'm interested in, in 1 function?

Since $R$ is rotated about the y-axis, I guess I have to make use of $$2\pi\int_{a}^{b} x (g(x)-f(x)) dx$$, but I'm not sure what my $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ would be in this case as I'm dealing with a circle in the first quadrant. Subtracting them like the formula suggest, would give me a function of two variables that I don't know how to integrate

Comment: You need to draw a picture of the given functions. Then, with respect to the y-axis, which curve represents the outer radius and which one the inner? Without a graph, solutions to problems like these are difficult to set up.

Comment: Are you trying to use the "disk method" or the "shell method"?

Comment: $$\pi\int_0^2(5-y^2)-(\dfrac{y}{2})^2\,dy$$

Comment: Ok, I see you solved each equation with respect to x, and this my g(x) and f(x) now. May I ask how you obtained the lower and upper limit? Wouldn't the upper limit be  $\sqrt{5}$ since that is the radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution given by @MyGlasses is correct, but if you want to do the integration in $x$ then you have to realize that there is no $g(x)-f(x)$. $y(x)$ is a piecewise continuous function given by

$$y(x)=2xu(1-x)+\sqrt{5-x^2}u(x-1), \quad x\in[0,\sqrt{5}]$$

where $u(x)$ is Heaviside function.

Then, the volume is given by

$$
\begin{align}
V
&=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{5}} xy(x)~dx\\
&=2\pi\left[\int_0^1 2x^2~dx+\int_1^{\sqrt{5}} x\sqrt{5-x^2}~dx\right]\\
&=2\pi\left[\int_0^1 2x^2~dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^5 \sqrt{5-t}~dt\right],\quad t=x^2\\
&=\frac{20\pi}{3}
\end{align}
$$